# AWK fixed record files

Tags: awk

Is there a way of using awk to deal with files without LF/CR to mark the EOL - fixed size "record/line" files, or that having the first 4 bytes indicating the size of the record?

Is there a way of assign $1, $2, ... to fixed "columns/fields" (without any separator)?

I tried but didn't found any solution just using awk - the only solution I found was to use another program that reads each record and then "pipes" the "line/record" to awk.

Thanks

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, provide sample input, the code you've written, the (wrong) output generated by your script and the (correct) desired output

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a way of assign $1, $2, ... to fixed "columns/fields" (without any separator)?*

In GNU `AWK` you might use [`FIELDWIDTHS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html) to work with fixed-width columns, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
01120
10150
11180
```

and imagine it has three columns - single, single, triple - then you might do

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 3"}{print $1, $2, $3}' file.txt
```

to get output

```
0 1 120
1 0 150
1 1 180
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't ends here, since there are fields which width depends on a previous field, so a previous field contains the width other field.

Comment: See [the first comment you got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69101031/awk-fixed-record-files#comment122129146_69101031) when you first posted your question for what you need to do for us to be able to help you.